# semantic error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type

Tags: configuration, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0, tsconfig

Here is the code [src/object.ts(50,58)](https://github.com/Panth977/sanitize-json/blob/master/src/object.ts#L50)

```
interface sanitizer<T> {
  (val: T): T
}

type MapSanitizor<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer P, ...(infer R)]
  ? [sanitizer<P>, ...MapSanitizor<R>]
  : [];

function isArrayAs<T extends any[]>(fn: MapSanitizor<T>): sanitizer<T> {
  return function(val) {
    if (!Array.isArray(val))
      throw new Error(`
        obj val \n
        = ${JSON.stringify(val)} \n
        is invalid value,\n
        value passed in isArrayAs is not an array
      `);
    const newlist: T = [] as any;
    for (let i = 0; i < fn.length; i++) {
      newlist.push((fn[i] as any)(val[i]));
    }
    return newlist;
  };
}
```

I am trying to build my package
it given me this error when i run `npm run build`

```
Error: D:/packages/npm/sanitize-json/src/object.ts(50,58): semantic error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.
    at error (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\node-entry.js:5400:30)
    at throwPluginError (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\node-entry.js:11878:12)
    at Object.error (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\node-entry.js:12912:24)
    at Object.error (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\node-entry.js:12081:38)
    at RollupContext.error (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:17237:30)
    at D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:25033:23
    at arrayEach (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:545:11)
    at Function.forEach (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:9397:14)
    at printDiagnostics (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:25006:12)
    at Object.transform (D:\packages\npm\sanitize-json\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript2\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:29277:17)
```

what have i done wrong? i dont see any error popup in vscode compiler.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? I put your code into the typescript playground and don't see any errors with the latest version (but i do on older versions)

Comment: You seem to be buildig with a TS version that is lower that 4.1

Comment: @NicholasTower
@TitianCernicova-Dragomir
[here is package.json](https://github.com/Panth977/sanitize-json/blob/master/package.json) `"typescript": "^4.9.4"`

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be some kind of configuration issue with `tsdx` and has little or nothing to do with the title or the tags.  Please [edit] the question to provide enough information to reproduce, including proper tags and any config info in plaintext (an external link in a comment doesn't suffice).  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz i have added correct tags & title, but no response got from new viewers, how do i let more experts know about this?

Comment: You tagged with "tds" which apparently means "Team Development for Sitecore".  Is that the right tag?